# How to make a gradient splash screen using TWA meta-tags?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradient, splash-screen, trusted-web-activity

Following the instructions at Google Developers site, I sucessfuly created my splash screen.

Using the meta-tag:

```
<meta-data
android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SPLASH_SCREEN_BACKGROUND_COLOR" 
android:resource="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

We can display a color in our app, but can we display a gradient?

I have tried to create a xml gradient and then reference it with `android:background` instead of `android:resource`, but it didn't work.

My gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="@color/color1"
        android:endColor="@color/color2"
        android:angle="135" />
</shape>
```

My colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="color1">#fafafa</color>
    <color name="color2">#212121</color>

</resources>
```

And the snipet added in the manifest.

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
```

As said, I just want to be able to use splash screen gradients using native TWA meta-tags, if possible. I got errors when I try to install the .apk (invalid package).

[Reference link: Google Dev Splash Screen](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa#making-a-splash)

Answer (score 0):

Only flat colors can be used as background for a Trusted Web Activity splash screen and drawables are not currently accepted in the Splash Screen.